# Is there a better way to build a table using the same source table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, select, ssms

This code works but I was wondering if there is a better way to do it? for each Select statement I am pulling from the same source and ultimately trying to move from a table with multiple rows (EAV style) into column like entries. Here is an image of the way the tables are structured at the moment:
[Current table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/folNB.png)
And here is an image of where I want to end up:
[new structure trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIRBq.png)

```
       SELECT * FROM
(SELECT 
        t1.a, 
        t1.b, 
        t1.c As c1, 
        t2.d AS d2, 
        t2.c As c2 
        FROM
(SELECT [Code],
      [DBName].[dbo].[Spec].SpecItem_Code,
      [DBName].[dbo].[SpecItem].Name,
      [DBName].[dbo].[Spec].SpecValue
  FROM [DBName].[dbo].[Vehicle]
  LEFT JOIN [DBName].[dbo].[Spec] ON [DBName].[dbo].[Vehicle].Code=[DBName].[dbo].[Spec].Code
  LEFT JOIN [DBName].[dbo].[SpecItem] ON [DBName].[dbo].[SpecItem].[Code] = [DBName].[dbo].[Spec].[SpecItem_Code]
  WHERE
  [DBName].[dbo].[SpecItem].Name LIKE '%test1%') t1
  FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT 
  [DBName].[dbo].[Vehicle].[Code],
      [DBName].[dbo].[Spec].SpecItem_Code,
      [DBName].[dbo].[SpecItem].Name,
      [DBName].[dbo].[Spec].SpecValue
      FROM [DBName].[dbo].[Vehicle]
  LEFT JOIN [DBName].[dbo].[Spec] ON [DBName].[dbo].[Vehicle].Code=[DBName].[dbo].[Spec].Code
  LEFT JOIN [DBName].[dbo].[SpecItem] ON [DBName].[dbo].[SpecItem].[Code] = [DBName].[dbo].[Spec].[SpecItem_Code]
  WHERE
  [DBName].[dbo].[SpecItem].Name LIKE '%test2%') t2
  ON t1.Code = t2.Code) t12
    FULL OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT 
  [DBName].[dbo].[Vehicle].[Code],
      [DBName].[dbo].[Spec].SpecItem_Code,
      [DBName].[dbo].[SpecItem].Name,
      [DBName].[dbo].[Spec].SpecValue
      FROM [DBName].[dbo].[Vehicle]
 LEFT JOIN [DBName].[dbo].[Spec] ON [DBName].[dbo].[Vehicle].Code=[DBName].[dbo].[Spec].Code
 LEFT JOIN [DBName].[dbo].[SpecItem] ON [DBName].[dbo].[SpecItem].[Code] = [DBName].[dbo].[Spec].[SpecItem_Code]
 WHERE
  [DBName].[dbo].[SpecItem].Name LIKE '%test3%') t3
  ON t12.Code = t3.Code
```

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/) and should be avoided (especially 4 part naming). Alias your objects and then use those to qualify your columns. It'll make your code *far* more succinct.

Comment: CTE is a great start. You could try to transpose the rows to columns but that would only work if you expect one row of results per (a,b).

Comment: you have to explain what this query is trying to do ,  sample data and desired output would help as well

Comment: Seems like this would be a better candidate for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: You are not even referencing a return column from your T3 alias.  Adding WHERE clauses of wildcard %testX% could also allow creation of a Cartesian result causing false expected results.

Comment: Before you post at [codereview.se], make sure to read [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778), as some things are done differently over there - e.g. question titles should simply say what the code *does*, as the question is always, "How can I improve this?".  Be sure that the code works correctly; include your unit tests if possible.  You'll likely get some suggestions on making it more efficient, easier to read, and better tested.

Comment: @TimothyG. when suggesting users post on CR it would be great if there was also a suggestion like "_Please read the relevant help center pages like '[What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)' and  '[How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)_". In the current form the code above would likely be closed as off-topic because it is missing context - the [sql tag](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/sql/info) has specific guidelines and OPs should read the tag info first to include sufficient info.

Comment: I included some images to explain better what I am trying to accomplish. I will look into CTE but mainly it will help clean it up not much else will be gained by it from my understanding.